I don't know where to put the binding.root as the old and new version are different
MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets

        }
    }
}

Here is the mainactivity.kt and after watching a tutorial I saw that they have setcontentview(R.layout.activity_main) changed to setcontentview(binding.root).
I dont know how to change.
I tried to change  ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main))
to binding.root but it doesn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
